# Methods of comparing strings in java and why this code returns with an error

Tags: java, string, if-statement, operators

Right now, I have the code written that is displayed below:

```
if(letterTwo.equals("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") && !"a" || "e" || "i" ||   "o" || "u".equals(letterOne));{}
```

The errors I am receiving are:
"The operator ! is undefined for the argument types string", and "The operator || is undefined for the argument types string, java.lang,string, java.lang.string"

I was wondering how I could fix this code, and what the operators are used for comparing strings like I need to.

Comment: you are comparing a character and not a String use character

Comment: @abcOfJava the comparison is wrong anyway, never mind "you are comparing  a character and not a String".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: `letterTwo` is a `String`

`letterTwo.equals()` expects a single `String` argument. Not the big boolean expression you are passing it.

You can either do

```
if (letterTwo.equals("a") || letterTwo.equals("b") || letterTwo.equals("c"))
{
    //etc
}
```

Or if your Java version is new enough you may be able to use a switch

```
switch(letterTwo)
{
    case "a":
    case "b":
    case "c": // stuff
              break;
}
```

If `letterTwo` is actually a char (which it may well be given the name...), you can do similar things but it is a bit easier:

```
if (letterTwo == 'a' || letterTwo == 'b' || letterTwo == 'c')
{
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
if (letter.equals("a") || letter.equals("b")
```

And so on. The point is that you have to use those boolean operators on expressions that have type boolean!

But of course, code as the above turns unreadable quickly. In the real world, such kind of checks would rather be done using a simple regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for you would be :

if( (letterTwo.equals("a") || letterTwo.equals("e") || letterTwo.equals("i")  || letterTwo.equals("o") || letterTwo.equals("u")) && !(letterOne.equals("a") || letterOne.equals("e") || letterOne.equals("i") ||letterOne.equals("o") || letterOne.equals("u")) ;{}

Please note, **this is not case-sensitive**. It would treat "A" and "a" differently.If you want them to be treated in same way use "equalsIgnoreCase" instead of "equals" above.

As pointed out by @GhostCat above, it distrubs readability and regex should be much better to handle such cases